# How do I change where cpan caches files?

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I'm trying to install a bunch of Perl modules.  I'm getting a lot of errors that look like this:

```
Cannot write to ‘/home/mayo/foo/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CH/CHROMATIC/SUPER-1.20190531.tar.gz.tmp10717’ (Disk quota exceeded).
```

How do I change the location of the .cpan directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cpan` likes to work out of `$HOME/.cpan`, and you probably don't want to try too hard to convince it to use something else.

The best advice is to make a symbolic link to `$HOME/.cpan` from a more bountiful file system.

Comment: Yeah, that thought occurred to me while I was driving home.  It works